# I am trying to write a batch script that will run automatically compressing third subdirectories using 7-zip

Tags: directory, zip, row, levels

**[

> My Pictures                                    [First directory row]
> Resized Pictures 1                            [second directory row]
> OriginalSizePics1 (OriginalSizePics13.zip)  [Third directory row]
> File21.jpg
> File22.jpg
> File23.jpg   Resized Pictures 2                           [second directory row]
> OriginalSizePics2 (OriginalSizePics2.zip)  [Third directory row]
> File24.jpg
> File25.jpg   Resized Pictures 3                           [second directory row]
> OriginalSizePics3 (OriginalSizePics3.zip)  [Third directory row]
> File26.jpg
> File27.jpg

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhVMU.jpg)**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your feedback,  i have no code writing experience. Acctualy I am not a developer, I am just a trier and code changer. I would be very happy if you could halp me. Best regards. Eduardo Koch